# My Dell Latitude D400 with Lubuntu 12.04 can find my wifi network... but can't authenticate the access. What could I check?

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, dell, intel-wireless

I'm an absolute beginner as an [L]Ubuntu user. The fact is my laptop **can find** any wifi network, but when I insert the password (which is absolutely right, I assure) it asks again for the password few seconds later and it keeps asking and asking and asking...

BTW I'm using this same laptop now, but with an wired network.

I have another computer, a desktop, with Ubuntu using the same wifi network. I've already tried to restart my router and any device. What else could I check?

This is what I have here:

```
01:03.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless LAN 2100 3B Mini PCI Adapter (rev 04)  
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2565
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 5
    Memory at fcfee000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: ipw2100
    Kernel modules: ipw2100
```

`$ dmesg | grep ipw210`

```
[ 20.552763] ipw2100: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2100 Network Driver, git-1.2.2 
[ 20.552768] ipw2100: Copyright(c) 2003-2006 Intel Corporation 
[ 20.552930] ipw2100 0000:01:03.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKB] -> GSI 5 (level, low) -> IRQ 5 [ 20.553507] ipw2100: Detected Intel PRO/Wireless 2100 Network Connection
```

`sudo iwlist scan`

```
Cell 03 - Address: bla bla 
ESSID:"finosuave" 
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bg 
Mode:Master 
Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6) 
Encryption key:on Bit Rates bla bla bla bla bla bla 
Quality:89 
Signal level:0 
Noise level:0 
IE: WPA Version 1 
Group Cipher : TKIP 
Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP 
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK 
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1 
Group Cipher : TKIP 
Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP 
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK 
Extra: Last beacon: 24ms ago
```

Comment: @VictorF Which encryption are you using?

Comment: Sorry, are you talking about password encryption? Partition encryption?

Comment: @VictorF encryption for your authentication type. WPA2 uses `tkip` or `aes`.

Comment: So, WPA2 using TKIP. Is it a problem?

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add output of `dmesg | grep ieee80211` and `dmesg | grep ipw2100`?

Comment: ...but `dmesg | grep ieee80211` does not return anything.

Comment: Sorry I meant dmesg | grep cfg80211

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `iwlist scan` I can see that your router is set-up to use both `TKIP` and `AES` encryptions. I had similar problem before with one of my network cards (it was supposed to support both encryption methods) and the solution was to configure my router to use only `TKIP`.

Comment: For now, I simple disabled my security, and it works... unsafely :(

Comment: Firstly I removed any authentication and it works perfectly. As we can't keep a unprotected network, we set the following: 

`SSID: My Network 
Channel: 3 
Security: WEP 
Key Size: 128 bit 
Authentication Type: Open System 
key 1: blabla1 key 2: blabla2 key 3: blabla3 key 4: blabla4` Well, WEP is a less protected standard, then the modem recommends that the keys should be changed frequently and requests 4 different keys.